# Binding and calling a method on a JS instance

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I have this:

```
function Person(number){
  this.number = number;
}

Person.prototype.wording = function(){
  if (this.person == 1){
    return "person is";
  } else {
    return "people are";
  }
};

var per1 = new Person(1);
console.log(per1.wording, '**');
```

I get logged out `[Function]`
how do I bind a method to an object or tell it to run that function when I call it on my instance

Comment: `wording` is a function, just invoke it using `per1.wording()`. Also, keep in mind that `this.person` will always be `undefined` (at least using the current code), perhaps you meant `this.number`?

Comment: Oh. May i misunderstood the is/are. New person(5);//are made no sense to me

Comment: @haim770 that was so special of me :/. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As haim770 pointed out, you need to invoke `per1.wording` by adding parentheses: `per1.wording()`.

Also, you probably meant `this.number`, instead of `this.person`.

```js
function Person(number){
  this.number = number;
}

Person.prototype.wording = function(){
  
  //changed this.person to this.number
  if (this.number == 1){ 
    return "person is";
  } else {
    return "people are";
  }
};

var per1 = new Person(1);

// invoked wording by adding ()
console.log(per1.wording(), '**');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(per1.wording());
```

This should fix it. 
My interpretation of your code, and how i would write sth like that correct me if im wrong:

```
var persons=[];
function person(name){
persons.push(this);
person.name=name;
}
function saypers(){
if(persons.length>1){
alert("Plural!");
}else{
alert("Singular!");
}
}
```

Do sth like:

```
albert=new person("albert");
saypers();//singular
einstein=new person("einstein");
saypers();//plural
console.log(persons);//albert, einstein
```